# Requiring that a function must be a retraction in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads, graph-theory

I'm envisioning an implementation of a monadic graph. I'll do my best to explain how it is to be constructed here.

The Graph type should be isomorphic to the following:

```
data Graph e v = Graph{ vertices :: [v], edges :: [(e, (v, v))] }
```

Where `e` is the edge type, and `v` is the vertex type, we include a list of vertices and a list of edges along with the vertices they connect.

What I'm envisioning is a monad instance of this type as follows:

```
instance Monad (Graph e) where
  return v = Graph v [] -- | Empty graph with one vertex
  m >>= f  = {- see below -}
```

I have an idea of how to implement `>>=` which basically takes each vertex, maps it to a new graph, and then re-connects the vertex which built each graph correspondingly based on how the original graph was connected.

For example, consider a function `f` which takes a vertex and produces the complete graph on two vertices (`K_2`) from it. Then if we bound `K_2` itself to `f`, we'd get something like:

```
A----B
|    |
C    D
```

where the graph `A----B` was the original, and the graphs `A----C` and `B----D` were produced from `A` and `B` respectively. In the end, `A` and `B` need to be connected since they were connected in the original graph. Note that `A` and `B` need not be *exactly* the same, but they need to directly map to something in the new graph. I'm leaving out some information for simplicity (what are the edges of the graph, etc), but the main point I've noticed is that for this to actually work as a `Monad` instance, `A` needs to be directly mapped to a vertex in `f A`, and the same goes for `B`. In general, each vertex in the original graph needs to be mapped directly to a graph in the graph resulting from `f`.

If I'm understanding correctly, this means that [**`f` must be a retraction for some other morphism `g`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retract_%28category_theory%29). If it is, we can clearly join the graph by connecting each morphed vertex in its resulting graph to the morphed vertices in the others, producing a new graph of the type we want.

Mostly this is just an idea I had, but I really wanted to if there is any way to, in Haskell, *require* that `f` be a retraction? Is there a way to state this within the confines of the language in order to supply an appropriate instance of `Monad` for a graph, or to do this, must I say "this is really only a monad if the function you're binding to is a retraction?" I suspect the latter, but I just wanted to check.

Alternatively, I may be understanding everything wrong! Feel free to correct me or give me some thoughts of your own.

Comment: If you impose any restriction on `f`, you don't have a monad.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to map each edge `(e,(a,b))` to a single edge `(e',(a',b'))`, where `a'` and `a'` are some representative vertices in `f a` and `f b`. It is not clear how you would choose these representative vertices. It is also not clear why you are imposing any connectedness requirements. Suppose `>>=` is a function that builds a graph where, if `a` and `b` are connected in `m`, then in `m>>=f` *each* vertex in `f a` is connected to *each* vertex in `f b`. What's wrong with this monad instance?

Comment: @n.m. Is there a structure that this "monad instance" *does* fit into? Also, there's nothing wrong with that instance, I guess I was just curious about whether or not this would work. What you suggested makes a lot of sense, though.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'structure that this "monad instance" does fit". I will show how you could modify your system such that `g` always exists. If you, instead of regular graphs, work with pointed graphs, i.e. graphs where exactly one vertex is marked (and there's always at least one vertex), then you have a natural way of having the `g` morphism and selecting a representative. The image of `(e,(a,b))` would connect the marked vertices of `f a` and `f b`. You can declare it `data PointedGraph e v = PointedGraph{ point :: v; vertices :: [v], edges :: [(e, (v, v))] }`

Comment: @n.m. That makes sense. But then I notice that the original `PointedGraph` need not really have a point for each vertex in the graph to be mapped to a new `PointedGraph` and `join`ed. Like, in my example above, `K_2` can have an arbitrary point; it's unnecessary information. I was asking if there's a mathematical structure (in Haskell or not) that describes the type of transformation I'm trying to perform. Maybe it's a silly question.

Comment: It's only unnecessary until you need it. You cannot have the point magically appear out of nowhere just when you need it and no sooner. Not constructively anyway. You can claim that any non-empty graph is pointed by the Axiom of Choice, but you cannot, you know, actually *find* the point. In Haskell, you can exploit the fact that a non-empty list has a head, and make it your point. (What to do if `f a` is an empty graph? You can just drop corresponding edges off `m >>= f`).

Comment: Note you are saying each vertex "need to directly map to something". This is just saying, in different words, that the image of each vertex is a pointed graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the comments say, you could use a pointed graph:

```
module PointedGraph where
import Control.Arrow (second)

data PointedGraph e v = PointedGraph { hops :: [(e, PointedGraph e v)], center :: v }
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Monad (PointedGraph e) where
  return = PointedGraph []
  PointedGraph hs c >>= f = PointedGraph (hs' ++ map (second (>>= f)) hs) c'
    where PointedGraph hs' c' = f c

connect :: PointedGraph e v -> e -> PointedGraph e v -> PointedGraph e v
connect g e g' = g { hops = (e,g') : hops g }

k2, ex :: PointedGraph String Int

k2 = connect (return 0) "original" (return 2)

ex = do
  n <- k2
  connect (return n) "derived" (return $ n + 1)
```

So this makes:

```
k2: 0 -original-> 2

ex: 0 -original-> 2
    |             |
    derived       derived
    |             |
    v             v
    1             3
```

Note that we have no checking for uniqueness of the vertex labels (that'd require an `Eq` constraint or the like) so we could easily have something like

```
k2 >>= const k2:

    0 -original-> 0
    |             |
    original      original
    |             |
    v             v
    2             2
```